# Storing timestamp with milliseconds in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

I know how to retrieve timestamp with milliseconds:

```
to_char(systimestamp ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF9')
```

Can anyone please advise, is the timestamp data type sufficient to store the date with milliseconds or can I use varchar2? I am trying to insert this value from Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `TIMESTAMP` allows precision down to nanoseconds if you want it.

If you only need milliseconds, you just want a `TIMESTAMP(3)` column.

Use a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) (which again goes down to nanoseconds, if you need it to) on the Java side. Note that you should *avoid* doing your `to_char` conversion if possible - perform any string conversions you need client-side; fetch data as a timestamp, and send it as a timestamp.

Comment: Thanks Jon , Is Date not allow to store milliseconds?

Comment: @user3457336: According to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413, `DATE` *does* include a time (surprisingly) but only down to seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use smart objects, not dumb strings. Use *java.time* for nanosecond resolution.

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class )
```

## java.time

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24448467/642706) is correct, but now outdated. The `java.sql.Timestamp` class is supplanted by the *java.time* classes such as [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) and `LocalDateTime`.

The *java.time* classes have a resolution of nanoseconds, more than enough for your milliseconds.

Oracle database [seems to have a `TIMESTAMP` type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006050) that is equivalent to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. That means it lacks any concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). For such a column, use [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) in Java as it too lacks any concept of zone/offset.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

For storing into a field of type similar to SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` where do have respect for zone/offset, use `Instant`:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment as fine as nanoseconds. In practice, we get microseconds in Java 9, but only milliseconds in Java 8.
```

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database via `PreparedStatement.setObject` and `ResultSet.getObject`. So use these smart objects rather than mere strings to communicate date-time values.

The *java.time* classes generate strings in standard ISO 8601 formats. Just call `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
String output = ldt.toString() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).